# Steamworks.Net invite to game not getting recieved

Tags: unity, networking, steam, steamworks

When sending an invite with `SteamFriends.InviteUserToGame(steamID, "")` the receiver doesn't get the invite, even though the InviteUserToGame function returns true as if the invite was sent. The other person can recieve messages sent through code, but the invites never go through.